# how to get the path before filename

Tags: c#, .net

I have a filename like "c:\temp\test\test.jpg", how can I get "c:\temp\test" directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using [`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)

Comment: Am wondering if I can add value with an answer of my own, but there doesn't seem to be much wiggle room here.

Answer (score 0):

I've always done things like this using the System.IO.FileInfo class. The DirectoryName property should help in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullFileName);
```